# d3.tsv does not recognize tabs on header row (d3 v3)

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I have trouble loading a tsv file correctly with d3. The function loads the correct number of rows, but only one column, displaying text in it with explict tabs character, as if it didn't recognize tabs on header row.

[image: Here is a picture of how the data is loaded]

I loaded it in RStudio and it works fine, so it seems that the files itself is properly formatted. Should I specify something more in the d3.tsv function ?

Python http server is set up correctly, and d3.csv works perfectly for another dataset.

> Edit : I was using a 2012 version of d3 v3. Updating to the latest release of d3 v3 fixed everything.

Comment: Can you share the TSV file? Not the whole thing, just a couple of rows and the headers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Kindly check your tsv file and version of your d3.js.
When i try to read a .tsv file, i am getting response as an object with key "columns" which gives value as the column names.

[d3.tsv response of a sample file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0W2Q.png)

Comment: I was indeed using an very old version of d3 v3 (2012). I updated to the last d3 v3 version available and it works fine. Thanks (I'll edit my kind of naive question then)